# Angular 4 + ngx-datatable: @swimlane/ngx-datatable 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I'm very new to Angular. I ran this to get my project started:
`git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart appName`

I updated it to Angular 4, everything should be good to go. Here's the output from running `ng -v`:

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.3
node: 6.11.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 4.0.3
@angular/compiler: 4.0.3
@angular/core: 4.0.3
@angular/forms: 4.0.3
@angular/http: 4.0.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.3
@angular/router: 4.0.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.3
```

I need a highly configurable table module `ngx-datatable` is a nice choice. I followed instructions on these pages:

https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/introduction/installing.html
https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/introduction/getting-started.html

I can run `npm start` and it loads up the app, but my browser encounters an error that breaks the app:

`GET http://localhost:3006/@swimlane/ngx-datatable 404 (Not Found)`

[image]

Here's my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                         from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }                            from '@angular/http' ;
import { NgxDatatableModule }                    from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

import { AppComponent }                          from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, NgxDatatableModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Part of my **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

My **systemjs.config.js**:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Spent the whole day working on this and I'm in the same spot. What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: I can't see `@swimlane/ngx-datatable` in your `dependencies`.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to your `system.config.js` > map

```
'@swimlane/ngx-datatable': 'npm:@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.js',
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you ever expect ngx datatable to load when you do not refer to it in your package.json. It needs this in your dependencies:

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^9.3.0"

Install then run.